# Kerberos + SharePoint

Tags: bcs, kerberos

Kerberos - the beast of SharePoint - has been configured and is creating tickets on my test environment WFE.  I also had RevertToSelf for the BCS service application turned on.  I am able to create an external content type/external list with the Authentication Mode turned to "User's Identity."  But when I attempt to access the list I get the dreaded "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."  The WFE event viewer is showing my domain account with Kerberos.  The App Server is showing Negotiate.

Is there another setting I am overlooking in Central Admin/IIS?  Is the difference in the WFE/App server for tickets an issue?  Why the heck does Kerberos have to be that difficult?  OK - maybe not so much that last question, but help getting BCS authentication working would be very appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm currently trying to setup BCS to pass through the current user's identity - web app running claims and kerberos and not having any luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are accessing data in an SQL server database through the BCS? if so - try to run this on the sqlserver

```
select DB_NAME(dbid), loginame,  sys.dm_exec_connections.auth_scheme from sys.sysprocesses join sys.dm_exec_connections on sys.sysprocesses.spid = sys.dm_exec_connections.session_id
where dbid>0
group by dbid, loginame,  spid, sys.dm_exec_connections.auth_scheme
```

this will show the actual connections on the database whether they are NTLM or KERBEROS, and if the user is actually delegated.

I guess you have set all the SPN's and all?

Comment: Yes, SPNs were set.  I will see if I can have the SQL cmd ran and update.  Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Any update? Facing the exact same problem here. SPNs are set, trusted delegation is set, still ANONYMOUS LOGON errors.

Comment: I'd like next steps as well.  I have SPNs registered for the web application and target database with delegation set, but it shows authentication as NTLM.